# Change background color in spark VideoPlayer

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex-spark

is there any way to change the black in background in the VideoPlayer component that comes with Flex 4 ?

I can change every color but i can't change the black in background.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if [this](http://docs.huihoo.com/flex/4/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#opaqueBackground) one option doesn't help you, use [this](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Spark+VideoPlayer) page to extend VideoPlayer with your own vision of logic, or if you are really have another option to add build your own component based on raw VideoDisplay like [this](http://www.riacodes.com/flex/basic-video-player-in-flex/).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample changing background color

http://blog.flexexamples.com/2009/05/04/setting-the-base-theme-color-on-a-spark-videoplayer-control-in-flex-gumbo/#more-1056